# Texture won't load - Three.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, three.js

I'm trying to load a texture for my mesh using three.js, but instead of loaded texture I'm getting plain black object. I did it as it is in three.js docs (https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader - Example) and also tried different solutions but nothing worked. Here is the code

```
//Creating The Sun model
const sunGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(16, 30, 30);
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('assets/images/sun.jpg');
const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }); // not working
//const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'skyblue' }); //working
const sun = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeometry, sunMaterial);

//Adding The Sun to the Scene
scene.add(sun);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Setting a mesh color works perfectly fine tho. Also tried using urls, no difference.
I'm using Angular and that code is in a constructor

Edit: image path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `renderer.render(scene, camera);` immediately after creating your `Mesh`, but at that time the texture hasn't loaded yet. Textures can take a fraction of a second to load, so by the time they're loaded the rendering has already taken place. If you're calling `render()` at 60 frames per second, you probably won't notice this delay, but if you're calling it only once, then you'll get a black material.

If you only want to call `render()` once **after** the texture has loaded, you should just use the `onLoad` callback [in the method outlined in the code example of the docs page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just simply put render to onload callback and everything works:)